# Obter parâmetro por da url para meu controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net

Preciso que meu controller obtenha um parâmetro de uma URL (`localhost/Check/123456`), onde `12346` seria o parâmetro.

Configurei o RouteConfig:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute("index", "Check/{id}", new { controller = "Check", action = "Indice", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
    }
```

Controller:

```
public class CheckController : Controller
{
    private Check _check;

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //_check.NumberOfregistrationUser = Convert.ToInt16(numberOfregistrationUser);
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Indice(long numberOfregistrationUser)
    {
        _check.NumberOfregistrationUser = Convert.ToInt16(numberOfregistrationUser);
        return Content(Convert.ToString(_check.NumberOfregistrationUser));
    }
}
```

Comment: Uma dúvida: por que pedir o parâmetro como `long` e depois convertê-lo para `short`?

Comment: Isso eu ajustei. Deixei todos como int

Comment: ótimo, agora é só mudar o nome do parâmetro e partir pro abraço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É pôr o parâmetro da *action* com o mesmo nome que foi definido na rota.

```
public class CheckController : Controller
{    
    public ActionResult Indice(long id) // <- trocar o nome do parâmetro
    {
        _check.NumberOfregistrationUser = Convert.ToInt16(numberOfregistrationUser);
        return Content(Convert.ToString(_check.NumberOfregistrationUser));
    }
}
```

Comment: Rodei o debbug, ao carregar a url nem chega nesse método no controller.

Comment: Então você tem mais rotas configuradas e elas estão conflitando.

Comment: Apenas duas, sendo uma delas default.

Comment: Inverta a ordem das rotas no RouteConfig